# Max-width in IE8, with width:100%?

Tags: css

Searched the internet but i cannot make it working. 
I have a simple html layout and i was testing it cross-browsers. Now i know that IE always has its peculiarities, so I was not that supprised that the max-width CSS code was not working. I was supprised though that I am not able to make it work. Here is what i have:

```
<style>
div.test{
    width:100%;
    max-width:650px;
    background-color:#333;
}
</style>
<div class="test">This is a test!</div>
```

This will just make the width of the TEST div 100%, even if it is larger than the 650px;. I am testing this in IE8. Anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the semi-colon after the `width:100%` declaration.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwJ88/

```
div.test{
    width:100%;
    max-width:650px;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Works just fine :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! Sorry, i forgot the ';' in my topic, but not in the actual code. Still it does not work here with IE8, are you using the same browser and version?

Comment: I am using Windows 7/IE 9 rendering as IE 7 and 8, and it works for me. There's definitely nothing else going on with your test page, something that could be interfering?

Comment: Nope, when i just use the code above the TEST div keeps getting widther than the 650px; also when i for instance try the script on http://netrenderer.com/

WEIRD??

Comment: Here's my test file, and it works in my render of IE 8, and in netrenderer.com :) http://www.mingteo.com/trials/trial-max-width.html

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your time. Adding the <html><head><body> tags fixed it... :)

Comment: Ah, so this will be the reason: if you don't have your `DOCTYPE` properly set, IE (7 and 8 at least, no idea about the newer ones) will force your page to render in Quirks mode, rather than standards-compliance mode, which will do an even more terrible job of rendering a page than its normal terrible job of rendering a page. Welcome to the world of IE headaches :)